# Dynamically run JUnit test methods

Tags: java, junit

How can a subset of different test methods be run *dynamically* using JUnit?

The goal is to have a jar file that can be invoked from the command line with arguments (e.g. `TestClass1#testMethod1,TestClass1#testMethod2,TestClass2#testMethod1`). Running a single test method can easily be done using:

```
Request request = Request.method('CLASSNAME', 'METHODNAME');
new JUnitCore().run(request);
```

But how can I add more test methods to the run? Ideally, this would not just repeat the `JUnitCore().run()` for every method, but combine all the defined methods to a single run. How can this be done?

Comment: Hi str , would you mean that you want to have the possibility to combine different test methods calls (already written) to create a test scenario without having to (copy/paste) code for such scenarios ?

Comment: @mbtdoor Yes exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can filter classes/methods to run:

```
    Request request = Request.classes(...
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldRun(Description description) {
            ... get class and method and decide...

        }
        @Override
        public String describe() {
            return null;
        }
    };
    request.filterWith(filter);
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. The `shouldRun` method is called for every class and then (what I was not aware of) for every method of that class as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use   `runClasses(java.lang.Class<?>... classes)` (Run the tests contained in classes).

http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runner/JUnitCore.html

Comment: `runClasses` runs (as the name implies) complete test classes. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: totally agree with you, maybe if you put your specific test in one class, would be a workaround...

Comment: Putting each method in its own class is definitively not option.